# Execute any Laravel command then with response we are getting html code

Tags: php, linux, laravel, centos

We are working on Laravel project and facing issue related to API response and Laravel command response.

When we execute any Laravel command then with response we are getting followings html code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Also Laravel API return response in body tag like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
API response in json format.
</body>
</html>
```

Same Laravel code working properly for other server. So could anyone suggest why we are getting such response with html tags?

FYI, we are using Centos7

Comment: Please provide a [mre]. How does your call look like? What exactly is sent? How is the code of the API?... etc.

Comment: What do you mean when you say "laravel command" ? A command on the command line?

Comment: When i run this command # php artisan migrate